# Convexity of composition: log and a sum of reciprocals

Tags: convex-analysis

Any suggestions on proving the convexity of

$f (\boldsymbol{x}) = \log \left ( 1 + \left (  \sum_i \frac {1}{\sqrt{x_i}} \right )^2  \right )$

where $\boldsymbol{x} = \left [x_1~x_2~\dots~x_L \right ]$ and $x_i > 0, \forall i$?

A straightforward way is to calculate the Hessian and check the semidefiniteness but that becomes ugly fast. Is there a simpler way?

UPDATE:
We can express $f (\boldsymbol{x})$ as $f (\boldsymbol{x})=g(h(\boldsymbol{x}))$ where $$g(z)=\log(1+z)$$ and $$h(\boldsymbol{x})=\left (  \sum_i \frac {1}{\sqrt{x_i}} \right )^2.$$
We know that $g(z)$ is quasiconvex and that $h(\boldsymbol{x})$ is convex. Thus, the result to the original question would follow if the following is true:

Is a quasiconvex function of a convex function convex?

Comment: You need more, as $g\circ id $ is obviously not convex.